# Is there a way to import Drupal variables into a the twig template?

Tags: 8, theming, configuration

I save a configuration setting using the following code.

```
$config = \Drupal::service('config.factory')->getEditable('report.settings');
$config->set('id', $values['id'])->save();
```

Is there a way to use this configuration in my twig template?

I thought about putting PHP code in the template, but it doesn't seem the PHP code added with `<?php ?>` is executed from the Twig template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't directly use these functions in a Twig file. Instead, you can preprocess the page and store your configuration settings in a variable that is passed to the template file, and display that variable in the template file.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $vars['new_var'] = $config->get('id');
}
```

You can render your variable with `{{ new_var }}`.

Comment: is it possible to use this on another page?  I have a configuration page form.  and then i want to use that id in another page